# Xamarin Android installs 3 times the same app on VS Emulator

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

Every time I debug, it installs 3 apps. I don't have idea why.

[Image of emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cX8bs.png)

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application android:theme="@style/Theme.Trunk"></application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: What does your manifest look like?

Comment: @RyanAlford I've edited the question with the manifest

Comment: Ok, so now you need to post where your `[Application]` tag is.

Comment: @RyanAlford [Application]
    public class MainApplication : Application, Application.IActivityLifecycleCallbacks

Comment: So maybe this is your problem. Where is the app's package ID set? Where is the version number set? Is it possible you have multiple manifest files?

Comment: Please provide the manifest generated on build. You can find it in obj/android I would think you have more than one Activity which has MainLauncher = true in the Activity attribute.

Comment: @RyanAlford I have only this manifest. What lines do you say I have to add to the manifest?

Comment: @Cheesebaron you were right! I had MainLauncher = true in 3 activities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments. You have probably copied the [Activity] attribute from somewhere and included `MainLauncher = true` in two other Activities.

Remove `MainLauncher = true` from those Activities and it should only show one launcher.